Mathematical expression of controlled Ry gate
"How can I describe the controlled Ry gate transformation on the ground state qubit using a mathematical formula similar to the one below, which is for the CNOT transformation?"
The example for the CNOT transformation can be:


What do you mean with "ground state qubit"? I guess $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ states judging by the CNOT formula. If so, I would rather use: "computational basis states".

Define the Ry gate as an operator on $\mathbb{C}^2$ via
$$R_y(\theta) = \exp\left( -i \frac{\theta}{2} Y \right) = \cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) \mathbb{I} - i \sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) Y = \begin{bmatrix} \cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) & -\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) \\ \sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) & \cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) \end{bmatrix}.$$
This already includes a rigorous formulation of the gate operation. If you are interested in a shorthand like the one you wrote, one could write
$$\lvert a \rangle \to \cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) \lvert a\rangle + (-1)^{a} \sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) \lvert a \oplus 1 \rangle$$
You could also write $\bar a$ instead of $a \oplus 1$ denoting the NOT operation. Depending on the calculation you are doing, the representation as a unitary matrix might be more handy, though.
EDIT: I misread your question, for the controlled version the above yields the same as @qubitizer's answer.
$$\lvert a, b \rangle \to \cos\left(a \frac{\theta}{2}\right) \lvert a,b \rangle + (-1)^{b} \sin\left(a \frac{\theta}{2}\right) \lvert a,b \oplus 1 \rangle$$

How about this:
$$|a,b\rangle \overset{CR_y(\phi)}{\to} |a, R_y(a \phi) b\rangle = \cos\left( \frac{a\phi}{2}\right) |a,b\rangle + (-1)^b \sin\left( \frac{a\phi}{2}\right)|a,\bar b\rangle $$
where we assume that $a,b\in \{0, 1\}$ as in your CNOT example and we define $\bar b := b \oplus 1$.

You need to split between $\vert 0 \rangle$ and $\vert 1 \rangle$, either by introducing the amplitudes:
$$
\alpha \vert 0 \rangle + \beta \vert 1 \rangle \rightarrow \left(\alpha\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) - \beta\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right) \vert 0 \rangle + \left(\alpha\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) + \beta\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right) \vert 1 \rangle
$$
or to describe the gate effect on each basis state separately:
$$
\begin{split}
\vert 0 \rangle \rightarrow \cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\vert 0 \rangle - \sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) \vert 1\rangle \\
\vert 1 \rangle \rightarrow \sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\vert 0 \rangle + \cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) \vert 1\rangle
\end{split}
$$
